# Can't open an URL with a Chrome Profile

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Path to the Chrome profile directory
chrome_profile_path = 'C:\\Users\\tan.le\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'
profile_name = "Profile 2"

# Create a Chrome options object
chrome_options = Options()

# Set the path to the Chrome profile
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") 
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={chrome_profile_path}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={profile_name}")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

# Create a new Chrome webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# The URL to open
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=ch%C3%BA+voi+connnn'

# Open the URL in Chrome
driver.get(url)
```

Log

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

***Error***:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.   (chrome not reachable)   (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

When I run, I got these errors and chrome can't open the URL which I set on the code above
Please help me fix this problem. I want to open an URL in Chrome with a Chrome Profile

Comment: Please provide the error-message.

Comment: In your question, not as a comment preferably :)

Comment: Did you try without `--remote-debugging-port=9222` ?

Comment: yes, I did try. But the result is same